# About computing the curl of a vector function

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, cross-product

Suppose we had a vector function $\textbf{F}=\begin{pmatrix}F_x \\ F_y \\ F_z\end{pmatrix}$. We can compute the curl of the vector function by computing $\nabla \times \textbf{F}= \begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial y}  \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \end{pmatrix} \times \begin{pmatrix}F_x \\ F_y \\ F_z\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial F_z}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial F_y}{\partial z}\\ \frac{\partial F_x}{\partial z} - \frac{\partial F_z}{\partial x}  \\ \frac{\partial F_y}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial F_z}{\partial x} \end{pmatrix} $.

My question is what "operation" are we doing when we carry out the cross product? Are we "multiplying" $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ by $F_z$ and subtracting $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ "multiplied" by $F_y$ to get the $i$ component of the cross product?

If so, what does it even mean to "multiply" a differential operator by a function?

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: Do you know the vector product is "just" the determinant of a certain matrix?

Comment: Yes, I do know that, but even so, what operation are you carrying out when you combine the partial derivative with respect to y and, F_z, e.g.?

Comment: You are differentiating the scalar function in the third coordinate of the vector field wrt the variable $\;y\;$ , for example: if $\;F(x,y,z)=(x^2-xyz, 2, zy^2-\sin y)\;$ , then $$\frac{\partial F_z}{\partial y}=2yz-\cos y$$

Comment: If you computed the vector product of two "numerical vectors", e.g. <1,2,3> and <4,5,6>, then the operation "dictating" the cross multiplication would be normal multiplication. Does the actual "operation" associated with the cross multiplication depend on the elements within the vectors?

Comment: @J If I understand you correctly, what is needed here is differentiation: for example, on the main diagonal of the matrix you have to do $$i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}F_z$$ and this means "partial diff. of the third coordinate function wrt $\;y\;$ , and this goes with $\;i\;$, meaning: in the first coordinate of the output vector. It is not *normal product* as with other determinants yet is something reminding us of "product" in some way, though it is differentiation.

Answer (score 2):

Technically $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ is an **operator**.  That is, a type of function whose domain is itself a set of functions.  Because it's a function, we could write it as $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(F_z)$ and say "the partial *of* $F_z$" (just like $f(x)$ is said "$f$ *of* $x$"), but most of the time the phrase we use is that we "apply" $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ to $F_z$ and write it without the parentheses, $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}F_z$ or $\frac{\partial F_z}{\partial y}$.

That said, we do write it like multiplication and even sometimes do like to think of it as a type of multiplication.  It shouldn't hurt if you think of it that way as long as you remember that this type of "multiplication" is **not commutative**.